# Hi, I am not sure if the sentence below makes sense. Could someone check it please?

Tags: grammaticality, british-english

"I have decided it is better to cancel the planned the Marc with Friends Playday previously planned  to take place in Spain this year."

"I have decided it is better to cancel the planned Marc with Friends Playday previously planned  to take place in Spain this year."

What I am not sure about is the "the" before Marc. Does it makes sense with the "the" in front?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You already have "the" in front of "planned", so you don't need to use it twice.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I also tought it but a friend of mine keeps telling me I should put the "the" in front of Marc too. Would this be incorrect?

Comment: Yes, it would. You should use "the" only once.

Comment: I've just noticed that you have used "planned" twice as well. You need it only once. If you eliminate the first use of it, you still need to leave one "the" there.

Comment: Thank you for your help